# CSS make half image overlapping text black or white, according to the image colors

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use `mix-blend-mode` difference to make it so half overlapping text changes according to the image behind it. With mix-blend-mode it doesn't work with black or white. Say I change it to red it does work, kind of (It's not exact colors). But still, I want it to be exact colors (only `#00000` or `#FFFFF`F) so I don't think `mix-blend-mode` is the way.

The thing that I can't find is that my background image has different colors. It's never fully black or white. it's a picture that the client can change so it should be working correctly with any picture.

[How it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2t1H.png)

[How it looks now 2, this is correct but just to showcase that image has different colors (it's a slider)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6pyY.png)

```css
  .horizontal-slider {
  .carousel-cell {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 10rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    .image-wrapper {
      width: 70%;
      height: 54rem;
      img {
        object-fit: cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
    .content-wrapper {
      top: 40%;
      width: 45%;
      h1 {
        color: $black;
      }
      @media (max-width: 47.938rem) {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="carousel-cell row justify-content-end">
  <div class="image-wrapper col-lg-10 px-0">
    <img class="mw-100" src="<?php echo esc_attr($image['sizes']['slideresize']); ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr($image['alt']); ?>" />
    <!-- Title & Par inside the slide-->
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrapper position-absolute start-0 text-start">
    <?php if ($title) { ?>
    <h1>
      <?php echo $title ?>
    </h1>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want it to look like this:

[image: How I want it to look]

Tried `mix-blend-mode` and `invert`. `mix-blend-mode`: difference on the image, image-wrapper, etc.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question accordingly and provide debugging details in the form of a [repro]. To make your code reproducible use parsed HTML Markup and not PHP. Also, Pay extra attention to the word minimal. Use only tags that are relevant to the question it self. The issue has nothing to do with either Javascript or PHP.

Comment: It looks like you uploaded the same image twice? I can not spot _any_ difference between the two.

Comment: @CBroe Oops! just changed them :)

Comment: @YukiDuki I invalidated your last edit to fix the other issues. Please insert the correct image again

Comment: @tacoshy Alright thank you!, I updated the question with more information. It seems to be connected to another question that says it has the answer. But what I have seems like a different problem and that question doesn't help sadly.